# Change index.html to index.php returns "save binary file"

Tags: php, node.js, socket.io

I have a problem with **changing file extension from .html to .php**. I need the .php extension because **I want to save the messages from chat to database**, so thats why I need .php extension. When I rename the file index.html to index.php and also I change it inside of the res.sendFile() method browser will return something like *"You are trying to save binary file. Do you want to save it?"*. Of course I'm running it on apache server. My OS is Ubuntu. I'm new to nodejs and socket.io, so it might be a silly problem. Express and Socket.io are also installed successfully. I'm enclosing my code:

```
// WORKING
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
   res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
// NOT WORKING
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
   res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.php');
});
```

Everything else is ok.

Comment: So you said that you are using node.js, by node.js u cannot use php... can you pls, give more information about your setup?

Comment: When I want to make route to my home page which is index.php it returns the error written above. When it is index.html it is ok. Is it what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

Node.js only supports JavaScript, but you can use node-php to run php with node js :
https://github.com/mkschreder/node-php

**NODEJS**

```
var express = require('express');
var php = require("node-php"); 
var path = require("path"); 

var app = express();

app.use("/", php.cgi("/path/to/wordpress")); 

app.listen(9090);

console.log("Server listening!");
```

Comment: Doesnt' work for me. It returns:{ [Error: spawn php-cgi ENOENT]
  code: 'ENOENT',
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn php-cgi',
  path: 'php-cgi',
  spawnargs: [] }
But thank you for answer.

Comment: unnecesary response to the question, nothing works and it's a mess try this code